# if I posted the answer what will happen to the bounty

Tags: discussion

I dunno if it is duplicate , I couldn't find a similar question on the site.

I set a bounty on my question , later on I knew the answer.
so if I posted the answer what will happen to the bounty ?.

Comment: The bounty is for "advertizing", it buys you more views on your question.  Posting an answer to the question does not change that in any way.  You cannot earn your bounty back, it was spent on the advertizing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing will happen to the bounty.

A bounty is a means to get attention to your question, much like an advertisement. Similarly, when you pay for an ad, you don't get your money back, whether it worked well or not.

Specifically, you cannot award a bounty on your own answer to your own question. If another answer comes in that is eligible for the bounty, that answer may get it automatically awarded if you don't award it by the time the bounty expires.